If I rotate a solid object, do the atomic nuclei also rotate?
Or is their orientation unaffected by the atomic electrons?

Atomic particles don't really "rotate" in a sense we would expect it would.

Rotation of an object (active rotation) equivalent to rotation of a coordination system  in inverse direction (passive rotation), Therefore in place of rotating nuclei you can rotate  reference frame.

@Polaris5744 Interesting. Could you expand on that or point me in the right direction?

I am not really an expert in atomic physics, so I don't really know what will really happen, but you could try and google "spin" of particles and see where will that brings you.

For the nuclei to rotate about their centre they must be coupled to the lattice. This can happen through so-called hyperfine coupling. For this the nucleus must have spin $I\geq 1/2$ and the solid must have magnetic polarisation, or $I\geq 1$ in combination with electric polarisation. Many elements have several naturally occurring nuclear isotopes. For example, for iron 2.2% of the atoms has $I=1/2$ and rest has $I=0$. If you reorient a magnetised piece of iron only those 2.2% will reorient along.
Note that for a nucleus with $I=0$ there is no way to define its orientation.

A solid consists of a lattice, which is formed by the nuclei. As the nuclear are not allowed to change their position, this lattice is fixed in space. Therefore, in this sense the nuclei follow the external rotation. However, this is a macroscopic view and it is not correct to infer that by rotating the object we change the angular momentum of the nuclei in a quantum mechanical sense.
